# Selecting properties for building dynamic SQL queries

Tags: c#, select, lambda, properties

I really don't like to hard code the name of properties of my models. So I came up with this code so far. My code is working fine and it does exactly what I want but in an ugly way. I'm pretty sure it will be problematic soon. So any help to improve it and make it work in the right way is appreciated. I'm looking to fine better way to extract selected property names without converting expression body to string. Any change to any part of this class is fine with me. Even changing usage as long as I don't hard code my property names.

What is the better way to extract selected properties name of a model?

Here is my code:

```
public class Selector<T> : IDisposable
{
    Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> Selectors = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>>();
    public Selector(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] Selector)
    {
        foreach (var select in Selector)
        {
            //string MemberName = CleanNamesUp(select.Body.ToString());
            //Func<T, object> NewSelector = select.Compile();
    #region Ugly Part 1

            Selectors.Add(CleanNamesUp(select.Body.ToString()), select.Compile());

    #endregion
        }
    }

    #region I am Doing This So I can Use Using(var sl = new Selector<T>())
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Selectors.Clear();
        Selectors = null;

    }
    #endregion

    #region Ugly Part 2
    private string CleanNamesUp(string nameStr)
    {
        string name = nameStr.Split('.')[1];
        if (name.Contains(","))
        {
            name = name.Split(',')[0];
        }
        return name;
    }
    #endregion


    public Dictionary<string, object> GetFields(T Item)
    {
        Dictionary<string,object> SetFieldList = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach(var select in Selectors)
            {
               SetFieldList.Add( select.Key , select.Value(Item)); 
            }


        return SetFieldList;
    }

    public List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetFields(IEnumerable<T> Items)
    {

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> SetFieldListMain = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> SetFieldList = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var select in Selectors)
            {
                SetFieldList.Add(select.Key, select.Value(item));
            }

            SetFieldListMain.Add( SetFieldList);
        }

        return SetFieldListMain;
    }

    internal List<string> GetKeys()
    {
        return new List<string>(this.Selectors.Keys);
    }
}
```

This is my model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime LockedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
User user1 = new User();
        user1.Email = "testDev@gmail.com";
        user1.UserName = "dora";
        user1.Password = "123456";
var UpObject = new Selector<User>( x => x.UserName, x => x.Password, x => x.Email, x => x.IsEnabled );
Dictionary<string,object> result = UpObject.GetFields(user1);
```

Comment: It's better to ask it in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid parsing the expressions as string if you instead parse them as System.Linq.Expressions.

Full code sample follows, but not exactly for your code, I used DateTime instead of the generic T, adapting should just be find&replace:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ExprTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Usage
            Expression<Func<DateTime, object>> propertySelector = x => x.Day;
            Expression<Func<DateTime, object>> methodSelector = x => x.AddDays(1.5);

            Expression[] inputSelectors = new Expression[] { propertySelector, methodSelector };
            #endregion

            //These are your final Selectors
            Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime, object>> outputSelectors = new Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime, object>>();

            //This would be in your Selector<T> constructor, replace DateTime with T.
            //Instead of CleanNamesUp you would decide which part to use by extracting the appropriate Expression argument's Name.
            foreach (Expression<Func<DateTime, object>> selectorLambda in inputSelectors)
            {
                Expression selectorExpression = selectorLambda.Body;
                string name = null;
                while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                    switch (selectorExpression)
                    {
                        #region Refine expression

                        //Necessary for value typed arguments, which get boxed by Convert(theStruct, object)
                        case UnaryExpression unary:
                            selectorExpression = unary.Operand;
                            break;

                        //add other required expression extractions

                        #endregion

                        #region Select expression key/name

                        case MemberExpression fieldOrProperty:
                            name = fieldOrProperty.Member.Name;
                            break;
                        case MethodCallExpression methodCall:
                            name = methodCall.Method.Name;
                            break;

                            //add other supported expressions

                            #endregion
                    }
                }
                outputSelectors.Add(name, selectorLambda.Compile());
            }

            //Set a breakpoint here to explore the outputSelectors
        }
    }
}
```

There could be a library for this, but i don't know about any, except [PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) for when you need to unify lambda arguments into one lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you forgot an important keyword 'nameof'. With the keyword, the code will be like this:

```
class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Tel { get; set; }
}

static Dictionary<string, object> GetFieldsOf<T>(T item, params string[] args)
{
    var properties = args.Select(property => typeof(T).GetProperty(property));
    return properties.ToDictionary(property => property.Name, property => property.GetValue(item));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var user = new User { Name = "Abel", Address = "Unknown", Tel = "XXX-XXX" };
    var result = GetFieldsOf(user, nameof(User.Name), nameof(User.Address));
}
```

This code will result in some performance problems caused by reflection. But fortunately, you can avoid these by emitting a small segement of code.

```
//MSIL
ldarg.0
call Property.GetMethod
ret
```

And replace it with proerpty.GetValue. These code can be generated and cached per type, which is still worthwhile.